# What is the expected value of most optimized future strategy?

Tags: conditional-probability, expected-value

My professor left us with the following question to work on for ourselves.

> Jay has a future and is going long. It will expire in 39 days. You
>   know beforehand it will go up 2/3 and down 1/3 of the days by 1$.
>
> When should you exit? What is the expected val of the optimal strategy?

Expected value of the future is 13 or +1/3 per day, but how does one optimize for a better expected value/exit strategy knowing only this?

Comment: Are they saying that after 39 days it will have gone up exactly 26 days and down exactly 13 days?  If that's true, then if you have had more than the expected number of down days stay in longer to recoup up days.  If you've had more than the expected number of up days, there may be some way of picking a best time to cash out early to avoid the down days.

Comment: Yes. But then you still do not improve the expected value. If you had more down days you're going to stay in because at the end you will be at +13. If you have more up days (best case scenario first 13 days are +1) you have 13 down and 13 up left.. So how would one improve?

Comment: My guess is that you would cash out on the first day that there are more down days than up days remaining. There's a decent chance there will be one or two like that at the end, but I'm not sure how you would calculate the expected value with so many ways it can turn out. There's too many possibilities to map out manually.

Answer (score 1):

This is an exercise in dynamic programming. I assume that all $\binom{39}{13}$ combinations of "up" and "down" days are equally likely.

Let $V(t, r)$ denote the expected value of the optimal strategy at time $t, 0 \leq t \leq 39$ when there are $r$ "up" days remaining, $0 \leq r \leq 26$. The function $V$ is only defined for valid pairs $(t,r)$, and not all pairs are valid. It is immediate that $V(39, 0) = 13$, and we wish to evaluate $V(0, 26)$.

Let $T = 39$. At time $t = T-1$, either $r = 0$ or $r = 1$. If $r = 0$, there is no advantage to staying, so we exit and win $V(T-1,0) = 14$. If $r = 1$, we stay and win $V(T-1,1) = 13$.

At time $t = T-2$, either $r = 0$, $r = 1$ or $r = 2$. If $r = 0$, we exit and win $V(T-2, 0) = 14$. If $r = 2$, we stay and win $V(T-2, 2) = 13$. If $r = 1$, then one of the remaining days is "up" and one of them is "down", with equal probability. Then 
$$V(T-2, 1) = \frac{1}{2} V(T-1, 0) + \frac{1}{2} V(T-1, 1) = 13.5.$$

One continues recursively, namely by
$$V(t, r) = \max\left(\frac{r}{T-t} V(t+1, r-1) + \left(1-\frac{r}{T-t}\right)V(t+1,r), 2(26-r)-t\right).$$
The above equation is a particular instance of the Bellman equation. The fact that there are two quantities in the maximum reflects the binary nature of our choices: stay or exit. The quantity $2(26-r)-t$ is how much we win if we exit at $(t,r)$, and is simply a rewriting of
$$\#\{ \text{up days by time } t\}-\#\{ \text{down days by time } t\} = (26 - r) - (t - (26 -r)).$$

Evaluating $V(t,r)$ is sufficient to determine an optimal strategy in this case, since we can simply evaluate both arguments of the maximum to determine whether to leave or exit. When I implement this in Python with memoization (caching already computed values of $V(t,r)$), I obtain $V(0,0) \approx 13.61$.